# DTD DOCTYPE declaration close before intended

Tags: xml, dtd, doctype

Hello fisrt time posting. i was doing a dtd to validate an xml and idk why when my code is readed the doctype declaration is closed with the ">" of the fisrt element of the dtd instead of at the end where the "]>" is placed. i have spend a few hours with this but no one of my friends knows xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE torneo [

<!ELEMENT torneo (edicion, anteriorGanador, participante+)>
<!ATTLIST torneo 
edicion CDATA #REQUIRED
anteriorGanador CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT participante (idP, pareja, nombre, edad, cabezaDeSerie?)>
<!ATTLIST participante 
idP ID #REQUIRED
pareja IDREF #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT nombre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT edad (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cabezaDeSerie (EMPTY)>
]>
```

Comment: What program are you using to validate your dtd?  Please include all error messages.

Comment: You specified `idP` and `pareja` as sub-elements of `participante` AND also as attributes, but haven't declared those two elements.  Same for `edicion` and `anteriorGanador`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `edicion` and `anteriorGanador` to be *attributes* of `torneo`, and `idP` and `pareja` to be *attributes* of `participante`.  To get this to work, just remove the specification of those attributes as sub-elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE torneo [

<!ELEMENT torneo (participante+)>
<!ATTLIST torneo 
    edicion CDATA #REQUIRED
    anteriorGanador CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT participante (nombre, edad, cabezaDeSerie?)>
<!ATTLIST participante 
    idP ID #REQUIRED
    pareja IDREF #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT nombre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT edad (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cabezaDeSerie (EMPTY)>
]>
<torneo edicion="a" anteriorGanador="zzz">
    <participante idP="xxx" pareja="xxx">
        <nombre>asdf</nombre>
        <edad>33</edad>
    </participante>
</torneo>
```

Comment: i just did that 10 minutes ago. Thanks you soo much for your time